# Long sites break the layout on the front page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The long name pushes the stats to a weird place. And what's with the "Stack Exchange" at the end anyway?

[image: Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange]

Comment: Yeah, the "Stack Exchange" is supposed to get stripped, not sure why it isn't. Nick'll have to sort it out, but I'll tweak the CSS to prevent it from happening in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed. We do replace the "Stack Exchange" when we import new Sites every week, but we don't update existing sites which is why these have lingered for a long time.

I went ahead and manually corrected the Sites that had the "Stack Exchange" in the name still.