# Cannot manually insert four spaces in front of long lines (like URLs)

Tags: bug, code-formatting, editor

I ran into a strange issue when posting [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296530/230261). I cannot  manually insert four spaces (to format as code) in front of the following line in the editor:

https://data.stackexchange.com/beer,%20wine%20&%20spirits%20stack%20exchange/query/new

This is what happens when I try:

> [image]

I *can* format it as code if I highlight it and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, so it is not a show stopper, but it's odd. It seems to occur when the word is too long for the word wrapping, e.g. the same issue occurs with:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Browser: Chrome 58 (Windows)

Comment: Similar issue--ctrl-k of code results in the four spaces appearing above the line being code-ified when that line is above a certain length.  Appears correctly in the body of the post.  I don't recall this ever happening before, and it's a bit odd when trying to do an edit.